# rails error Class must exist - Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I ask this question here because I don't find any answer that resolve my problem. I want to create a post belong_to travel, so each travel have many post. But when I create the Post I have on my view this error message :

1 error Prohibited this article from beign save
Travel must exist

So here is my travel.rb file :

```
class Travel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And my post.rb file :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :travel

  geocoded_by :country
  after_validation :geocode
end
```

Does someone know where is the problem and could explain me a solution ?
Thank a lot !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails 5 makes `belongs_to` association required by default. So you cannot create `Post` without associating it with  a `Travel`

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
@post.travel = travel
@post.save
```

If you want to make the association optional, you will have to mention it explicitly

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :travel, optional: true
end
```

Comment: Hi ! thank you for the answer, but I haven't Post.create in my posts_controller.rb, I use this method : @post = Post.new(posts_params) and I passed these params in the new method : (:title, :country, :description)

Comment: Right, however you create the post object, you have to make sure its associated with the travel object before you save it

Comment: @AntoninMrchd `@post = Post.new(params); @post.save` is (basically) a longer version of `Post.create(params)`.

Comment: Ok I understand, but how can I do that ? like that : `@travel = @post.travel` or adding :travel in my post_params ?

Comment: If you can pass `travel_id` as parameter from your form, then post should automatically be associated with that travel

Comment: When I add the line `@post.travel = travel` I have this following error : `undefined local variable or method `travel' for #<PostsController:0x007f9e14589a08>`

Comment: I find the error ! I create a helper method in my application controller and create a method called current_travel and I define that inside : `@current_travel ||= Travel.find_by(params[:id])` ! thank you all for your answer !